# Infinispan Server CLI authentification

Tags: authentication, server, command-line-interface, infinispan

I tries to start Infinispan 10.1.3 in server mode. But after security configuration I have following error in CLI:

[disconnected]> connect
Username: admin
Password: ********
The user is not allowed to access the server resource: ISPN000287: Unauthorized access: subject 'null' lacks 'ADMIN' permission

In result I can't connect to my Infinspan server via CLI :(

I created all Infinispan configuration exactly according documentation:

in file infinispan.xml I added:

```
   <security>
     <authorization> 
        <identity-role-mapper /> 
        <role name="all" permissions="ALL" />
        <role name="reader" permissions="READ" />
        <role name="writer" permissions="WRITE" />
        <role name="supervisor" permissions="READ WRITE EXEC"/>
     </authorization>
  </security>
```

...

```
  <endpoints socket-binding="default" security-realm="default">
     <hotrod-connector name="hotrod">
       <authentication>
         <sasl mechanisms="SCRAM-SHA-512 SCRAM-SHA-384 SCRAM-SHA-256 
                           SCRAM-SHA-1 DIGEST-SHA-512 DIGEST-SHA-384
                           DIGEST-SHA-256 DIGEST-SHA DIGEST-MD5 PLAIN"
            server-name="infinispan" 
             qop="auth"/> 
       </authentication>
     </hotrod-connector>
     <rest-connector name="rest"> 
       <authentication mechanisms="DIGEST BASIC"/>
     </rest-connector>
  </endpoints>
```

In file users.properties I added:
admin=123

In file groups.properties I added:
admin=admin

Answer (score 0):

The CLI uses the REST API. I'm not sure if your configuration is correct, but I'm fixing some issues that might be related just now. Will be probably released in the next 10.1.x version
https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-11525

Update:
If you upgrade your 10.1.x version, it should work now